# How to use twitter typeahead.js to select an option in a select control from a json array

Tags: jquery, json, twitter-bootstrap-3, typeahead.js

I need to figure out how to use twitter typeahead.js to select an option in a select control from a json array. [this is a bootstrap3 site]

I got typeahead.js working pretty easily almost default:

```
var countries = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('name'),
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  limit: 10,
  prefetch: {
    url: '[[!~36]]',
    filter: function(list) {
      return $.map(list, function(country) { return { name: country }; });
    }
  }
});

countries.initialize();


$('#scrollable-typeahead .typeahead').typeahead(null, {
  name: 'countries',
  displayKey: 'name',
  source: countries.ttAdapter()
});
```

the url refers to a modx resource that returns a json formatted array:

```
[
    {
        "id": 59,
        "label": "fname lname 561280"
    },

..... shortened .....

    {
        "id": 73,
        "label": "fname lname 333333"
    }
]
```

and my html looks like:

```
<span id="scrollable-typeahead">
<input type="text" placeholder="Candidate search" class="typeahead form-control input-md" id="typeahead-clients">
</span>

<select id="client_id" name="client_id" class="form-control input-md combobox"  required="">
    <option value="59">fname lname 561280</option>
..... shortened .....
    <option value="73">fname lname 561280</option>
</select>
```

So I have 2 problems:

1. the typeahead does not work because the json is an array of arrays, how can I set this up so that the typeahead uses the 'label' for the search and the id to match the option value in the select box?
2. how do I get the typeahead to auto select the matching option in the select box once a user makes their selection?

I'm only doing it like that for a fallback if a users browser has issues with the javascript, they can still use the drop down. - if there is a better [cleaner] way to do this please suggest it.

Answer (score 1):

Ididn't solve this but got a nice workaround using: http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/index.html#documentation